# Python: Writing File after modifying contents

Tags: python, nltk

I just would like to delete HTML tag and then re-save file in same file..
text files have html tags..

```
import shutil
import os
import nltk

low_firm=['C:/a1.txt','C:/a2.txt']

for aa in low_firm:
    f= open (aa,'r+')
    for bb in f:
        raw = nltk.clean_html(bb)
        raw2=str(raw)
        f.write(low_firm)
```

but it doesn't work! I got a message....

```
IOError: [Errno 0] Error
```

Comment: Your file list is called `low_firm` but you are iterating over `all_firm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would open a file to read, read all its content as lines in a list, close the file and then reopen it to write on it:

```
for aa in all_firm:
    r = open (aa,'r+')
    lines = r.readlines()
    r.close()
    w = open (aa,'w')
    for bb in lines:
        raw = nltk.clean_html(bb)
        raw2=str(raw)
        w.write(low_firm)
```

This is because I feel it is easier to rewrite the entire file when it contains text (instead of register or other binary data). *Almost* always it is not *too* slow to be done on text files, since text files are not as big as, let us say, databases files. It may not be the better solution for you but I would recommend to try it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your file list is called `low_firm` but you are iterating over `all_firm`.

You should also close the file after you are done writing to it.